# Finding the difference between two rows in SQL and assigning a numerical value to it (SQLite)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table

| name | login_time |
| --- | --- |
| John | 2021-01-02 08:10:52 |
| John | 2021-01-02 11:55:01 |
| John | 2021-01-04 17:36:22 |
| Amy | 2021-01-02 10:12:48 |
| Amy | 2021-01-06 11:22:41 |
| Amy | 2021-01-06 19:05:07 |

I want to add a usage_days column. If the same user login within the same day of his last login time, it is considered as the same day. The resulting column should look something like this:

| name | login_time | usage_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2021-01-02 08:10:52 | 1 |
| John | 2021-01-02 11:55:01 | 1 |
| John | 2021-01-04 17:36:22 | 2 |
| Amy | 2021-01-02 10:12:48 | 1 |
| Amy | 2021-01-06 11:22:41 | 2 |
| Amy | 2021-01-06 19:05:07 | 2 |

Comment: use a window function to count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We might need to know your exact database to render an exact answer, but the following would probably work:

```sql
SELECT name, login_time,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY CAST(login_time AS date)) usage_days
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY name, login_time;
```

Comment: I am using SQLite. What modifications do I need if I were to consider login within 4 hours of last login time to be the same usage_period ?

Comment: @Carlos I have no idea how to do that in SQLite, which has poor date support.  But...that's not the question you asked.  What you _did_ ask, I have answered above.